# Find and replace all matching strings within textarea

Tags: jquery, text, replace, area

I have this

```
var textarea=$('#content'); 
textarea.html(textarea.html().replace("PID","111111"));
```

This works partially, but it only finds the first "PID" within the textarea and replaces it to "1111111". There are about 7 others I need to change as well.  What I need is a way to find ALL "PID" and replace it with "111111".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use regex to replace all the occurrences in a string. Try this

```
textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(/PID/g,"111111"));
```

Answer (score 18):

```
textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(new RegExp("PID","g"),"111111"));
```

the "g" modifier performs a global search.