# Change image source attribute in string HTML and return string HTML again

Tags: javascript, html, string, html-parsing

I have html web page and i want to download this web page as pdf. So that i convert this web page to string, and i must sent to the service. Namely i have unchanging string html. I can't add indicator for split string html. When the html web page too large with base 64 string images, i must change this base 64 string with avatar image url (Because it is too large to send data with json).  i have short html string with changing base 64 string and then i can send to the service side to download pdf. I have an HTML string (it looks like my real html string) see below:

```
var stringHTML = 
"
<div id="myDiv">
   <img src="abc" /></div>
   <img src="abc" /></div>
   <img src="abc" /></div>
   <img src="abc" /></div>
</div>
";
```

I want to change image `src` attribute value to `xyz`. Namely I want to convert the HTML string to:

```
stringHTML = 
"
<div id="myDiv">
   <img src="xyz" /></div>
   <img src="xyz" /></div>
   <img src="xyz" /></div>
   <img src="xyz" /></div>
</div>
";
```

How can change this source attribute values with return again string value ? Namely i must have string html after change operation..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace all matching strings within textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809172/find-and-replace-all-matching-strings-within-textarea)

Comment: And just so you know both of your snippets are not valid JS code. You can't jump lines and indent the string like that.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the linked [possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809172/find-and-replace-all-matching-strings-within-textarea), you would do something like this:

```
stringHTML = stringHTML.replace(/abc/g,"xyz");
```

or

```
stringHTML = stringHTML.replace(new RegExp("abc","g"),"xyz");
```

It's also worth noting that your current string is not valid.  You'll either need to replace the opening and closing double-quotes (`"`) with single-quotes (`'`) or escape the double-quotes used inside the string.  And, as Ivan mentioned in the comments, javascript cannot span lines without special allowances (escaping the newline, etc).  You could define it like this, I think:

```
let stringHTML = ' +
    <div id="myDiv"> +
      <img src="abc" /></div> +
      <img src="abc" /></div> +
      <img src="abc" /></div> +
      <img src="abc" /></div> +
    </div>';
```

You could also create an array and join it immediately:

```
let stringHTML = [
    '<div id="myDiv">',
        '<img src="abc" /></div>',
        '<img src="abc" /></div>',
        '<img src="abc" /></div>',
        '<img src="abc" /></div>',
    '</div>'
].join('');
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202782/declare-a-string-var-with-multiple-lines-in-javascript-jquery) for more on multiline string definition.